# restrict concurrent request + node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have an api exposed using node.js. I have to restrict the API call only once at a time. I tried the following approach.

**app.js**

```
globals.consumed = false;
```

**routes.js**

```
app.get("/route1", checkForAlreadyConsumed,controller.method);
```

**controller.method**

```
globals.consumed = true;
//Business logic goes here
//After all the stuff is done
globals.consumed = false;
```

**checkForAlreadyConsumed**

```
checkForAlreadyConsumed() {
   if(consumed == false) {
      next();
  } else {
    retrun res.send(403);
  }
}
```

So by above logic i am try to make nobody should consume that API if its already doing its process. `But by the above approach if i do 2 concurrent calls , the second call is waiting for the first call to finish so the 403 code is sent as response to frotend`. Plz share your ideas.

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is still not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish beyond what is already being done by the code you posted.

A clear problem description is necessary to understand and solve the problem. Describe step by step what the expected experience & behavior is.

Comment: Sounds like you are solving the wrong problem. The concurrency check should probably be at a lower level. This only solves for a single node process, which prevents scalability all around. I'm also questioning why you need this concurrency block to begin with.

Comment: @jishi My API involves lot of processing so i dont want anybody to hit that API twice to make sure not to dump the node process. So i want any user to wait till the previous processing is done. While the process in inProgress and another user hits the API i would like to say the user plz wait its in process.

Comment: @AndreasPizsa plz see my above comment

Comment: Sounds like the processing should not be done in the request but rather continuously (or on data change) in the background, only serving the last processed data to everyone calling that route. But what do I know :)

Comment: @jishi Thanks for your time. I couldn't get your point.Can you plz elaborate??

Comment: I'm just saying that it sounds like you are solving the wrong problem (see http://xyproblem.info/). Doing work on a GET request which has the potential to kill your server sounds like something you want to avoid altogether, not even making it user triggable. If you could provide (in your original question) a more detailed picture of what  processing you are actually doing, maybe we could provide you with a better solution.